# Translate SQL to Python, if possible

Tags: python, sql

Is there a tool to convert a sql statement into python, if it's possible. For example:

```
(CASE WHEN var = 2 then 'Yes' else 'No' END) custom_var
==>
customVar = 'Yes' if var == 2 else 'No'
```

I am trying to provide a API for ETL-like transformations from a json input. Here's an example of an input:

```
{
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "David",
    "Transformation: "NewField = CONCAT (ID, Name)"
}
```

And we would translate this into:

```
{
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "David",
    "NewField: "4David"
}
```

Or, is there a better transformation language that could be used here over SQL?

Comment: I am curious, what's your Use-Case? I don't know any tool which can or wants to do this ...

Comment: I would have translated it as `custom_var = 'Yes' if var == 2 else 'No'`. But anyway, what would you do with this tool?

Comment: It's for an ETL api. Where someone can enter in json with their SQL statement they would use, and we would do the translation on our side in python.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) applies here.

Comment: Why use SQL fragments inside the JSON rather than either evaluable Python or (more safely and conveniently) some transformation language for your product?

Comment: @LarryLustig -- what would be a better transformation language in this case? I just need to provide some syntax for the user -- and I'm thinking the most common etl language would be SQL.

Comment: A domain specific language built for your project.  SQL is a very poor text / data manipulation language -- there are very few standard functions and they tend be verbose and clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `SET NewField = CONCAT (ID, Name)` actually valid sql? (if Newfield is a variable do you need to declare it and prefix with "@"?). If you want to just execute arbitrary SQL, you could hack something together with sqlite:

```
import sqlite3
import json

query = """
{
    "ID": "4",
    "Name": "David",
    "Transformation": "SELECT ID || Name AS NewField FROM inputdata"
}"""

query_dict = json.loads(query)

db = sqlite3.Connection('mydb')
db.execute('create table inputdata ({} VARCHAR(100));'.format(' VARCHAR(100), '.join(query_dict.keys())))
db.execute('insert into inputdata ({}) values ("{}")'.format(','.join(query_dict.keys()),'","'.join(query_dict.values())))

r = db.execute(query_dict['Transformation'])
response = {}
response[r.description[0][0]] = r.fetchone()[0]

print(response)
#{'NewField': '4David'}

db.execute('drop table inputdata;')
db.close()
```

Comment: no I was thinking everything to the right of the `=` would be the SQL expression.

Comment: well you can parse your input string however you want!